# Literature suggestion for "strong convexity"

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Does anyone know of a reference that discusses strong convexity and strong smoothness of proper convex functions over Banach spaces?

All the references I find only deal with the finite dimensional case.